# Python consecutive file creation and writing speed problem

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a lot of data to multiple files but the writing process gets slower as the process continues.

I tried this process on HDD and SSD and got the same time on both.

Here is example code:

```
for i in file_names:
  with open(i, "w") as file:
    file_cache = ""
    for l in lines:
      if condition:
        file_cache += l + "\n"
      elif condition_2:
        file_cache += l + "\n"
    file.write(file_cache)
```

I'm open to any ideas to speed this up.

Comment: Why not just use `file.wrilelines` rather than writing your own loop to do that? Depending on the size of the data, of course building up a string is going to get slow; it's a [Schlemiel the Painter's algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm)

Comment: That ^^^ is supposed to be `file.writelines` of course.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried this, but it took the same time as the **write** command.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the writing that gets slower but the processing you're using string concatenation naively here :

```py
    for l in lines:
      file_cache += l + "\n"
```

try replacing it with :

```py
"\n".join(lines)
```

that should fix your issue.

Comment: There's no reason to combine the lines into a single string before writing them and even if you do, you'd want to do it once outside the loop instead of repeatedly for every file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the actual code is much more complex. I included this code just as an example. My main problem about write speed not collect the data.